# How come this edit got pass the review? What is the best course of action if you feel edit is wrong?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, edits

Straight up, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2607156) is the edit in question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919302/how-to-set-selected-tab-in-uitabbarcontroller-using-storyboard) is the full question.

I am not saying the edit is bad, I am just saying I couldn't understand how the edit improved the question.

I rejected the edit, because I thought

1. It wrongly used code format for non code segments.
2. Replaced a word "programmatically" with "problematically" completely
   against the meaning of the sentence.

I normally not much into reviews, and don't have too much experience in doing edit reviews. So whenever I try to review, I use 'Skip' option more than the other two. But this time I thought reject was the better option.

And I am asking the below questions, with a belief that the edit was wrong on both of those above counts. If my belief is wrong, then below question doesn't stand.

Okay my questions are

1. What is the correct use of code formatting? In the context of the
   question(edit) the editor use code formatting to **Storyboard**,
   which I know is an iOS programming feature but surely nothing to use
   code tags for. If it is **UIStoryBoard**, then things can be
   different.  Now consider that the edit has only code formatting
   error(error 1), should I reject the edit?
2. What should you do if the edit being approved is wrong? Remember you
   can only edit the post only after existing edit is peer reviewed
   completely. I can think of 2 (probably 3) course of action.

   - You can **reject** the edit, and wait until the community take the    final decision. If the edit got approved, you are free to
     edit now    and you can correct it. But you need to wait for
     sometime, and I had    the misfortune once or twice when this time
     span took around 1 hour.
   - You can look at the current edit status, and see if edit is getting    approved or rejected. For example if the edit already has
     2 approve    votes, you can also choose approve so that the edit is
     completely    reviewed. Now you are free to edit and correct it, but
     you then    helped the original editor gets 2 reputation point for a
     wrong edit,    and also **failed to educate him that the edit is
     wrong**.

P.S : Regarding second of those question, I know there is an **improve** option there which can be used to edit a post even if existing edit is being peer reviewed. But after you improve the post, you need to take a decision by selecting whether or not the original edit is helpful or not.

Comment: Faulty edits get approved. It happens. Rollback/fix the post, and move on unless you see consistent, bad behaviour from specific users. In that case, flag and move on.

Comment: Because three people thought it was a good edit.

Comment: btw problemmaticaly is from original post(see edit history)

Comment: @RiaD sorry. I didn't saw that. You are right.

Comment: @RiaD, just because it's from the original post doesn't mean the word is used correctly (my eyes bled a little when I saw the edit comment).

Comment: There was a conflicting edit. It happens. Fix the error caused by the editing conflict and move on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and all, I edited the post. I still have doubt about the last sentence, so kept it as is. Rest I believe has been fixed